# Why this div is overlaping the one before?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I dont really know how to ask it, dont know what error is this. Im very nob.

Im trying to order this divs, but the detalle_info is overlaping the one before (notice there white words).

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

http://tinyurl.com/cb8m37u

Comment: You might want to provide an example of the problem occurring - either using a tool like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.org), or a screenshot.

Comment: This is a client-side question - so GET RID of your server-side code and show the HTML + CSS.

Comment: Sorry, this is the site: http://tinyurl.com/cb8m37u Im using Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the `<div>` with id `namecost` has a fixed height 30px, just remove it. Removing that height will make the div resizable depending on its content.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem was another. As @Billy moar sugested, I fixed. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In #tabscontent your tabs2 and tabs3 DIVs are within the tabs1 DIV. Move them out of there and hopefully it should be fixed.

Comment: Great! It solved it. Edit: Really not, the solution was another point, but your sugestion is great. I need to fix that also.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a height of 30px but the content doesn't fit in that height.

Comment: Thanks, as other user sugested. Here was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make your blocks float, nothing more complicated.
Use float:left on your div.
By the way, you don't need a div per sentence.
(don't forget to put a clear:both at the end)